# Find the corner of a tetrahedron

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The corners A(13, 16, 8) B(-19, -8, 4) C(16, 13, -4) of the tetrahedron ABCD are given and it's know that the centre point M of the circumsphere belongs to the X,Y-plane. The corner D has to be found, knowing that it also belongs to the line g= P(21, 4, 16) Q(15, 13, -2).

Comment: Here is a plan of action:  $AB$, $BC$, $CA$ have three perpendicular bisector planes. Find two of them. Find their intersection, which is a line. The circumcenter is on this line. Find its intersection with $xy$ plane, that would be the circumcenter $O$. Now find the radius $R$ of that sphere. Find the equation of $PQ$, and a point on it that is $R$ unit away from $O$. There may be two answers. That would be a bit of work along the lines of Calculus II,III.

Comment: Thanks. I think I figured it out in another way, however. I solved a system with two equations: the radius BM = AM and BM = CM where M(u, v, 0) is the centrepoint of the sphere. Once solved for u and v I found the point of tangency between the sphere and the line g. That point is the missing corner of the tetrahedron.